# Using a shapefile as mask with rasterio mask gives different affine transforms with rasters of the same projection and resolution

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, masking, array

I have a list of n file paths to geotiffs of the same resolution and projection but with varying extents. In brief the goal is to

1. use Rasterio's mask module to use a shapefile containing a single polygon feature that is the mutual overlap of all the geotiffs to open each geotiff cropped to the the mask as an array,
2. use numpy vstack to build a 3d array with a depth of n, and
3. use the the affine transform of the masked array to write out a multiband raster.

The issue I'm running into is that mask function returns out different affine transforms for thedifferent geotiffs. Given the same proj and resolution and same mask geometry, I expected that the affine transform returned from the mask function would be the same and that could be used to save out the multiband raster. Since that is not the case, using the a single affine transform to write the arrays back to raster results in misalignment between the bands. When just looking at the source geotiffs in QGIS they all seem aligned. Here's some code of the approach, example output of the different transforms, and some of the source raster info

```
import geopandas as gpd
from rasterio.mask import mask

def geofunc(listofpaths):
    arrlist = []
    afflist = []
    for pth in listofpaths:
        arr, aff = mask(rio.open(pth), shapes=msk.geometry, crop=True)
        arrlist.append(arr)
        afflist.append(aff)
    return arrlist, afflist

msk = gpd.read_file(aoishp)  # aoishp is a path to a shapefile
arrs, affs = geofunc([path1, path2, path_n])

## The mismatched transforms
affs[0]
Affine(12.5, 0.0, 328675.256933,
       0.0, -12.5, 6822881.355124)
affs[1]
Affine(12.5, 0.0, 328669.934103,
       0.0, -12.5, 6822872.680881)

## Some info of the rasters
rio.open(proclist[0]).crs       #  proclist is the list of paths
CRS.from_epsg(32612)
rio.open(proclist[1]).crs
CRS.from_epsg(32612)
rio.open(proclist[1]).bounds
BoundingBox(left=328569.934103, bottom=6776610.180881, right=419257.434103, top=6851810.180881)
rio.open(proclist[0]).bounds
BoundingBox(left=328675.256933, bottom=6776693.855124, right=419112.756933, top=6851706.355124)
rio.open(proclist[0]).res
(12.5, 12.5)
rio.open(proclist[1]).res
(12.5, 12.5)
```

Comment: Looks like the 3rd column of the transform is the translation to the centre(?) of the bbox in each case which will change with each raster. Also I wouldn't expect the pixels of those two to align